# Array pointer aliasing - undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, pointer-aliasing

Does the following code invoke undefined behavior (due to aliasing violation or otherwise)?

```
int foo(int (*a)[10], int (*b)[5])
{
    (*a)[5]++;
    return (*b)[0];
}

int x[10];
foo(&x, (int (*)[5])&x[5]);
```

Note that the corresponding code using plain `int *` rather than pointer-to-array types would be perfectly legal, because `a` and `b` would be pointers to the same type and thus allowed to alias one another.

**Edit:** The interesting consequence, if this is in fact an aliasing violation, is that it seems to be a hackish but valid way to get `restrict` semantics pre-C99. As in:

```
void some_func(int *aa, int *bb)
{
    int (*a)[1] = (void *)aa;
    int (*b)[2] = (void *)bb;
    /* Now **a and **b can be assumed by the compiler not to alias */
}
```

Presumably if you needed to access an actual array at each address, you could use SIZE_MAX-1 and SIZE_MAX-2 etc. as the differing sizes.

Comment: They're pointers to the same type, they cannot be assumed not to alias.

Answer (score 6):

You are not accessing objects through pointers of different type here: you are not manipulating the array objects to which `a` and `b` point themselves but the objects pointed to by `(*a)+5` and `(*b)+0`, namely `*((*a)+5)` and `*((*b)+0)`. Since these are pointers to the same type they may well alias to the same object.

The implicit assignment by the `++` operator is a valid assignment to the object pointed to by `(*b)+0`: `++` is equivalent to `x = x + 1` (besides `x` being evaluated only once) and for simple assignment `=` the standard says

> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object
>   that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the
>   overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall  have qualified or
>   unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is
>       undefined.

The types here are exactly the same and the overlap is exact.

Comment: +1 Very interesting. Though, I still hate all this pointers semantics stuff…

Comment: By this logic, wouldn't accessing `int[5][5]` and an overlaid `int[25]` also be valid...?

Comment: @R.. yes, I think it would be valid. Arrays are somehow in a grey zone. For a `struct` it is clear that accessing a field `toto.x` accesses the object as a whole, `A[24]` and `B[4][4]` are defined by pointer arithmetic and thus never access the array as a whole.